# If our Panasonic microwave shuts off after 2 seconds, is it likely a door latch or magnetron issue?

Tags: electrical

Need some help with our Panasonic Inverter NN-SD681S. Very light use and in perfect condition except that it suddenly started shutting off after 2 seconds.  All other functions are fine (lights/power fine, timer works, etc) After it turns off, power is still on, just goes back to the main "menu"

When I hold the door in tight and a minuscule bit "up" (maybe 1/16 of an inch movement, literally the tiniest visible amount) it works perfectly and does not shut down. The second I let go of the door it shuts off . The door closes and secures normally, but I guess is off by a tiny bit that makes the difference. Googling and looking on this site I see this likely means there is a door latch issue, or possibly the magnetron.

Is this accurate? If so, what exactly do I need to fix/replace and is safe to do? Wasn't sure if it's just securing/moving an internal part or actually replacing something. DH has some electrical experience so as long as nothing will blow up, he can probably do it.

Comment: In case of confusion this refers to a microwave oven

Comment: Panasonic has crap latches. Mine had a cheesy plastic "ramp" latch that wore down in less than a year with normal family use, resulting in the same problem. I lived with it for a bit (wriggling made it work) until some other problem caused the unit to short out and quit working. I brought it back and swore off that brand forever.

Comment: Ugh, definitely don't want that. What a waste of $200! I'd rather put the cash towards a new one since though rather than a repairman. The one time I let the CC extended warranty lapse! It is such a waste b/c otherwise, it's pretty much near new/perfect. I guess I'll see if there's somewhere I can donate it to who can safely fix it. Thanks for the replies! So frustrating, one little millimeter lol.

Comment: If the magnetron was faulty, it would not heat. Or if it over heated, the flame and temperature sensor would cut the electricity to it all. Or if it drew too much current, would trip a GFCI or blow the internal fuse. Anything resetting it would indicate a logic board or latch issue. In most microwaves, the primary latch failure would trigger a logic board power relay to turn off.

Comment: Outside chance: Check airflow through various grills and vents. Unlikely to have a sensor but ... .  Dist buildup blocks air paths and cause overheating but usually >> 2 seconds. If a fam is not working the system may detect that and phut down. Also just maybe turntable rotation motor - but O'd mot expect that to cause shutdown.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed a door latch issue; however, you're best off referring this to a microwave oven technician (they exist, although much of their business comes from foodservice not residential).  Microwave ovens contain a dangerous HV transformer and capacitor: the transformer will supply several kilovolts at several hundred mA, and the capacitor is well over a microfarad.  Furthermore, the door latch interlock is a critical safety system on a microwave oven -- if it fails or is bypassed, you can get into a situation where the microwave tries to start cooking *you* as well as whatever food you put inside!

Answer (score 1):

Definitely the door latch. I pushed my door up and down about 1/16 of an inch and it started working. I took cover off ( after unplugging ) and adjusted the mechanism and it works fine now.

Comment: Enjoy fixing your own things, but do be careful.  Microwaves are one of a few types of appliances that can actually kill you for reals if you touch the wrong things inside them.

Comment: @Billy C.: You should have added "even if unplugged". Any appliance can kill you if plugged in while working on it.

Answer (score 1):

As reported by others, this is a door latch issue.

Oven would work perfectly fine if I kept the door open and manually pressed the door-latch button with my finger. This alone fixed my issue for two weeks.

When it broke again, this led me to the realization that the push-knob on the door wasn't pressing the door-latch button in far enough.

Workaround fix was to take a couple of cigarette filters and sellotape them to the end of the push-knob. Blue-tack or anything else small and sticky might work. The effect is to extend the length of the push-knob to keep the door-latch button sufficiently pushed in for the oven to stay on.

Comment: Stand well back when using!